# NSOpenGLView Cocoa (again)

Tags: cocoa, opengl, xcode4, nsopenglview

I'm new to the whole Cocoa/Objective-C malarky (but have years of C/C++ on *nix).

I'm trying to create a basic Cocoa application that is filled with an NSOpenGLView. I have:

chink.mm

```
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import "chink.h"

@implementation chinkView

@synthesize window;

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching : (NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLog(@"Danger, Will Robinson! Danger!");
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

and chink.h

```
@interface chinkView : NSOpenGLView {

    NSWindow *window;

}


@property (assign) NSWindow *window;


@end
```

I have a single .xib set up like

https://skitch.com/cront/ri625/chinkxib

where 'chink View' is set as delegate for Window and File Owner.

I'm getting an 'invalid drawable' error (even before the application finished launching), which to my understanding means that it is trying to instantiate the opengl view before the window (although I'm probably wrong).

What I want is the solution to this problem of creating the window and setting the opengl view inside it. Once this is done I have absolutely no problem writing the OGL (like I said, I know C++) but all this NS calls gunk is alien to me.

I'm not looking for 'why don't you do it in SDL/GLUT' answers please. Just the code to make it create the window properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I sacked off this approach.

Went the long route and changed to this:

chink.mm

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <OpenGL/gl.h>
#import <OpenGL/glu.h>

#import "chink.h"


@implementation chinkNS

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat * pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:(NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute[]) {
        NSOpenGLPFAWindow,
        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
        NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 32,
        nil
    }];
    if(pixelFormat == NULL)
        NSLog(@"pixelFormat == NULL");
    [pixelFormat autorelease];

    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect pixelFormat:pixelFormat];
    if(self == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Could not initialise self");
        return NULL;
    }

    [[self openGLContext] makeCurrentContext];
    [self initGL];

    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowWillMiniaturize:) name:NSWindowWillMiniaturizeNotification object:[self window]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidMiniaturize:) name:NSWindowDidMiniaturizeNotification object:[self window]];

    animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:animationTimer forMode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:animationTimer forMode:NSModalPanelRunLoopMode];
    lastTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)frame
{

    NSLog(@"Chink is up and running. Let's do this thing!");

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0); 
    glFlush();

    [self drawGL];
    [[self openGLContext] flushBuffer];



}

#pragma mark OpenGL

- (void)initGL { }

- (void)reshapeGL { }

- (void)drawGL { }

- (void)animate:(float)dt { }

#pragma mark Event Handling

- (void)timerFired
{
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    [self animate:currentTime-lastTime];
    lastTime = currentTime;
}


#pragma mark Loose ends

- (void)setFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [self reshapeGL];
}

// To get key events
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}


@end
```

and chink.h

```
@interface chinkNS : NSOpenGLView
{

    NSTimer * animationTimer;
    NSTimeInterval lastTime;

}

- (void)initGL;
- (void)reshapeGL;
- (void)drawGL;
- (void)animate:(float)dt;

@end
```

The same settings in the .xib except that it is a standard NSView that subclasses my opengl view.

I was hoping for a simpler, more elegant set up as above but you can't win 'em all.

Closed.